# How to create new object using classname stored in variable and how to pass another variable into this class's constructor?

Tags: php

I have classname stored in variable $classname; also I have an array of values I should pass into object constructor.

```
$classname = "MyClass";
$variables = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I need

```
$objInstance = new MyClass(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

How?

Thank you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
$r = new ReflectionClass($classname);
$objInstance = $r->newInstanceArgs($variables);
```

Comment: +1 Nicely done ! Didn't think about Reflection -- but, once again, it helps doing what seemed impossible ;-)

Comment: Great solution! Since SPL isn't documented good yet, here is PHP SPL Reflection class description http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/4/0

Answer (score 5):

```
$objInstance = new $classname($variables[0], $variables[1], $variables[2], $variables[3]);
```

Comment: I'm guessing he doesn't want the list of parameters to be hard-coded like this

Comment: though I'm guesing this might be quicker than reflection and thus quite usefull in some cases

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.3, you can use [Argument unpacking via `...`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) to unpack an array into argument list as in: `new $classname(...$variables)`.

MWE:

```php
<?php
class MyClass{
  function __construct($a,$b,$c,$d) { echo "$a, $b, $c, $d\n"; }
}
$classname = "MyClass";
$variables = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$objInstance = new $classname(...$variables); // Outputs: 1, 2, 3, 4
```